# Can sunspot search inside array?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I have the next model with a array field:

```
Class Invitation
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
 include Sunspot::Mongo

 field :recipients, :type => Array
 attr_accessible :recipients

 searchable do
  text :recipients do
  recipients.map { |recipient| recipient }
  end
 end

end
```

I have in my controller:

```
def recipients

 @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
 @search = Invitation.search do |s|
 s.fulltext params[:search]
 s.with(:recipients, @invitation.recipients)
 end

@recipients = @search.results
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
  end

end
```

This when I reindex not show error but:

**This not works fine for me**. I get the next error in log:

Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError (No field configured for Invitation with name 'recipients'):

I have tried too:

```
string :recipients do
  recipients.map { |recipient| recipient }
end
```

But I get the next error when I reindex:

```
recipients is not a multiple-value field, so it cannot index values []
```

**Can I do fix this problem?**

Comment: I dont know any Ruby, but do you have a field `recipients` that is `multi-valued=true`?

Comment: recipients is an array with 4 email addresses. I have now this: `string :repins, :multiple => true do
     repins.map { |repin| repin }
     end`. The problem now is that I get the error **NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for ["#<Invitation:0xc8cf684>"]:Array):**

Comment: The fix for this question is add `:multiple => true` and fix the problem **recipients is not a multiple-value field, so it cannot index values []**. I go open other question with the last problem.  Thank you! @aitchnyu

Answer (score 7):

The `Invitation` model has a `has_many` association with `recipients`. This means an `invitation` can have multiple `recipients`.

So, try this:

```
string :recipients, :multiple => true do
  recipients.map { |recipient| recipient }
end
```