# Can I index multiple values for one object using sunspot solr and rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

Can I index multiple values for one object using sunspot solr and rails 4?

For example, I have a one to many relationship between users and specialities tables

```
class user
has_many :specialities

class speciality
belongs_to :user
```

Since, user can have multiple specialities, can we index multiple specialities under single user?
If so, how to define it in the searchable method in user.rb?

```
# Solr indexing for users table
searchable do
  text :first_name
  text :last_name
end
```

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718584/can-sunspot-search-inside-array ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working. I am able to search users based on their specialities.

user.rb

```
# Solr indexing for users table
searchable do
  text :first_name
  text :last_name
  text :user_specialities
end

def user_specialities
  if self.specialities.present?
    return self.specialities(:select=>:name).map(&:name).join(',')
  end
end
```